# Angular configuration through HTTP GET

Tags: angularjs, configuration

I need to load some config data like assets url using HTTP GET request how can I configure my app to fetch this data in config section?

I tried using a service but service object is not accessible in angular config section.
I tried using provider as well here is the code

```
angular.module('app', [
]).service('configuration', ['api', function(api) {
    var app = {
        s3Url:'',
        config:{}
    };

    this.fetchS3Url = function(){
    //$http call
       app.s3Url = api.getS3url();
    };


}]).provider('bootstrapper', function() {

    this.load = function(mytext) {
      alert();
    };

    this.$get = ['configuration', function(configuration) {
        var that = {};
        that.test = function() {
            console.log(configuration);
        };
        return that;
    }];
}).config(['bootstrapperProvider', function(bootstrapperProvider) {
//how can I call configuraion service method
}
]);
```

Comment: `config` phase can only access `provider` & `constant` you need to change `configuration` service to `provider` to get access of it inside provider

Comment: even if I make it a provider I am unable to access $http service does that means I have to use $ajax over here ? And is this the best approach to provide configuration or I should create separate boot.js file to manually bootstrap the application

Comment: The function within the service that calls the http that initialize your configuration service, will return a promise. Store that promise within the service. Then within the first state of your app use the state resolve to depend on that service stored promise response. When that response is resolved the state will be kicked off. That way you will not have to guess how many seconds your HTTP call will take.